# Kusanagi ワードプレスの初期設定の仕方を教えてください

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, mariadb

ダウンロードして立ち上げましたが、「データベース接続を設定」の画面で何を入力してよいのか分かりません。通常のワードプレスをローカルにインストールした経験は有りますが、その場合はphpmyadminにてデータベースを構築して、ユーザーネームはroot、パスワードはxxxxxxx等簡単に入力して次のステップに進めましたが、Kusanagiの場合はどうすれば良いのですか。
立ち上げた時点でのアウトプットは以下です

```
(base) nobu@nobu-IdeaPad-3-15IIL05:~/.kusanagi$ sudo docker-compose up
[sudo] password for nobu: 
Starting kusanagi-data ... done
Starting kusanagi-mariadb ... done
Starting kusanagi-php5    ... done
Starting kusanagi-php7    ... done
Starting kusanagi-nginx   ... done
Attaching to kusanagi-data, kusanagi-mariadb, kusanagi-php5, kusanagi-php7, kusanagi-nginx
kusanagi-mariadb    | 210614  1:44:35 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.0.24-MariaDB-1~jessie) starting as process 1 ...
kusanagi-php5       | [14-Jun-2021 01:44:36] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
kusanagi-php5       | [14-Jun-2021 01:44:36] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
kusanagi-mariadb    | 210614  1:44:35 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
kusanagi-mariadb    | 210614  1:44:35 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
kusanagi-mariadb    | 210614  1:44:35 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
kusanagi-mariadb    | 210614  1:44:35 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
kusanagi-mariadb    | 210614  1:44:35 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
kusanagi-mariadb    | 210614  1:44:35 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
kusanagi-mariadb    | 210614  1:44:35 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
kusanagi-php7       | Cannot load Zend OPcache - it was already loaded
kusanagi-mariadb    | 210614  1:44:35 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
kusanagi-php7       | [14-Jun-2021 01:44:36] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  Module 'apc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
kusanagi-php7       | [14-Jun-2021 01:44:36] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  Module 'apcu' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
kusanagi-php7       | [14-Jun-2021 01:44:36] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
kusanagi-mariadb    | 210614  1:44:35 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
kusanagi-mariadb    | 210614  1:44:35 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
kusanagi-php7       | [14-Jun-2021 01:44:36] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
kusanagi-mariadb    | 210614  1:44:35 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
kusanagi-mariadb    | 210614  1:44:35 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
kusanagi-mariadb    | 210614  1:44:35 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.28-76.1 started; log sequence number 1616737
kusanagi-mariadb    | 210614  1:44:35 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
kusanagi-mariadb    | 210614  1:44:35 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
kusanagi-mariadb    | 210614  1:44:35 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@4f6314a820fe' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
kusanagi-mariadb    | 210614  1:44:35 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
kusanagi-mariadb    | Version: '10.0.24-MariaDB-1~jessie'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
kusanagi-nginx      | nginx: [warn] "ssl_stapling" ignored, issuer certificate not found
status      
kusanagi-php7       | 172.19.0.6 -  14/Jun/2021:01:45:09 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/setup-config.php" 500
kusanagi-php7       | 172.19.0.6 -  14/Jun/2021:01:45:57 +0000 "GET /index.php" 302
kusanagi-php7       | 172.19.0.6 -  14/Jun/2021:01:45:57 +0000 "GET /wp-admin/setup-config.php" 200
kusanagi-php7       | 172.19.0.6 -  14/Jun/2021:01:48:42 +0000 "GET /wp-admin/setup-config.php" 200
kusanagi-php7       | 172.19.0.6 -  14/Jun/2021:01:48:46 +0000 "GET /wp-admin/setup-config.php" 200
```

上記にて最初に気づいたのは`nginx: [warn] "ssl_stapling" ignored, issuer certificate not found status`のエラーです。Google検索した結果Pleskにて直せるそうですが、それ以外の手法はありませんか。

[KUSANGI Runs on Dockerの使い方](https://github.com/prime-strategy/kusanagi-docker/blob/master/HowToUse_RoD.jp.md#kusangi-runs-on-docker%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84%E6%96%B9) にコマンドが載っていますが、 以下を入力しても駄目でした。

```
(base) nobu@nobu-IdeaPad-3-15IIL05:~/.kusanagi$ ls
bin                 HowToUse_RoD.md  LICENSE    update_version.sh
docker-compose.yml  install.sh       README.md
HowToUse_RoD.jp.md  lib              RoD.png
(base) nobu@nobu-IdeaPad-3-15IIL05:~/.kusanagi$ kusanagi-docker --dbname wordpress_test
no such sub command --dbname
Try kusanagi-docker -h
INFO: Done.
(base) nobu@nobu-IdeaPad-3-15IIL05:~/.kusanagi$ kusanagi-docker --dbuser nobu
no such sub command --dbuser
Try kusanagi-docker -h
INFO: Done.
(base) nobu@nobu-IdeaPad-3-15IIL05:~/.kusanagi$ kusanagi-docker --dbpass tennis33
no such sub command --dbpass
Try kusanagi-docker -h
INFO: Done.
```

設定の経験のある方、教えてください。

Comment: [Wordpressのインストール](https://kusanagi.tokyo/document/wp-install/)を確認すると事前に[KUSANAGIのプロビジョニング](https://kusanagi.tokyo/document/kusanagi-provision/)を実施する必要がありますがこちらは実施しましたか？

Comment: @keitaro_so 助言ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

サブコマンド provision が抜けています。

kusanagi-docker **provision** --dbname wordpress_test --dbuser nobu --dbpass tennis33

Comment: `(base) nobu@nobu-IdeaPad-3-15IIL05:/media/nobu/NTFSUbuWin/Wordpress/my_wp_project$ kusanagi-docker provision --dbname wordpress_test --dbuser nobu --dbpass tennis33
ERROR: Target name requires [a-zA-Z0-9._-] 3-24 characters.
ERROR: Failed.`

Comment: provisionするプロファイル名がいります。
https://github.com/prime-strategy/kusanagi-docker/blob/master/HowToUse_RoD.jp.md#provision
のprovisionにあるパラメータを全て指定します。
kusanagi-docker -h でも使い方を見ることができます。
provision [options] --fqdn domainname target(like kusanagi.tokyo)
optionsはその下に書かれているものです (--dbnameとか--dbuserとか)